# Convert RGBA to NRGBA

Tags: go, colors

I am trying to return the pixels that have changed and their color. The following func works fine, but it does not give me the 255,255,255 value i require. Is it possible to convert it to the format required?

I already looked at the documentation here -> https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/

I also tried different conversions manually, but i cannot get it to work. Does someone know how to convert this in golang?

```
type Pixel struct {
    x, y  int
    r, g, b, a uint32
}

func  diffImages(imgOne *image.RGBA, imgTwo *image.RGBA) []Pixel  {
var pixels []Pixel

bounds := imgOne.Bounds()
diff := false

for y := bounds.Min.Y; y < bounds.Max.Y; y++ {
        for x := bounds.Min.X; x < bounds.Max.X; x++ {

            r, g, b, a := imgOne.At(x, y).RGBA()
            rt, gt, bt, at := imgTwo.At(x, y).RGBA()

            if r != rt || g != gt || b != bt || a != at {
                diff=true
            }

            if diff == true {
                pixel := new(Pixel)
                pixel.x = x
                pixel.y = y
                pixel.r = rt
                pixel.g = gt
                pixel.b = bt
                pixel.a = at
                pixels = append(pixels, *pixel)
            }

            diff = false
        }
    }
return pixels
}
```

If there is another better or faster way to get the required output than i am willing to accept.

Note: I am new to go.

Comment: Please show an example of what you tried, what the output was, and what you expected to see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean this? I did other refactors, your code seemed needlessly complex.

I haven't tested this, didn't test images.

```
// Pixels are pixels.
type Pixel struct {
    x, y  int
    color color.NRGBA
}

func diffImages(imgOne image.RGBA, imgTwo image.RGBA) []Pixel {
    var pixels []Pixel

    bounds := imgOne.Bounds()

    for y := bounds.Min.Y; y < bounds.Max.Y; y++ {
        for x := bounds.Min.X; x < bounds.Max.X; x++ {

            if !reflect.DeepEqual(imgOne.Pix, imgTwo.Pix) {

                rt, gt, bt, at := imgTwo.At(x, y).RGBA()
                pixel := new(Pixel)
                pixel.x = x
                pixel.y = y
                pixel.color.R = uint8(rt)
                pixel.color.G = uint8(gt)
                pixel.color.B = uint8(bt)
                pixel.color.A = uint8(at)
                pixels = append(pixels, *pixel)
            }
        }
    }
    return pixels
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It might be complex, because i am only used to python, ruby and php. The question also might seem to easy for some. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Dany: is this is working there's probably something else incorrect going on, because you're taking alpha-premultiplied values, and putting them directly into a non-alpha-premultiplied color (this is going to re-multiply your alpha channel against the RGB values)

Comment: @JimB It seems to be working, but i cannot tell for sure now. I am still working on learning to code go with this project. Is there another way to convert RGBA to NRGBA and get the pixels that have changed?

Comment: @Dany: is the alpha channel always 255? You can see that if there an alpha, the RGBA output has to be different: https://play.golang.org/p/I0Gm--mlGk. Why do you need to "convert" to MRGBA? (assuming the values weren't supposed to be NRGBA to begin with)